# React Native FlatList with snapToInterval accumulates offset when scrolling

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to create a horizontal FlatList in React Native where each item takes up 33% of the screen width. I'm using snapToInterval to make sure that the list snaps to these items. However, I'm facing an issue where a small offset accumulates as I scroll through the list, causing the items to eventually misalign.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, Image, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const imageWidth = width * 0.33;

const images = [
  require("../../../assets/sequencesIcons/1.png"),
  // ... other images
];

function SequenceIconSelector({ selectedIcon }) {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(images[parseInt(selectedIcon, 10) - 1]);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ width: imageWidth }}>
      <Image source={item} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", resizeMode: "contain" }} />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={images}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      horizontal
      snapToInterval={imageWidth}
      decelerationRate="fast"
    />
  );
}

export default SequenceIconSelector;
```

Answer (score 0):

i eventually changed 0.33 to 0.33333333333 so the difference is too small to be noticed .